# how to store classobject that returns self

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I am making a NSObjectClass that has a method in it that returns self.

This is what it looks like roughtly

**storageclass.h**

```
// storageclass vars go here

- (storageclass)assignData:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
```

**storageclass.m**

```
//@synthesise everything

- (storageclass)assignData:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {

//assign values from dictionary to correct var types (i.e. NSString, Int, BOOL)
//example
 Side = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Side"];
return self;

}
```

Then what I want to do is use this class by passing a NSDictionary var through its method to return a object of type storageclass that I can then use to access the vars using dot notation.

this is how I am trying to access this class at the moment

**accessorViewController.h**

```
storageclass *store;

@property (strong, nonatomic) storageclass *store;
```

**accessorViewController.m**

```
@synthesize store;

- (void)getstoreready {

[store assignData:someDictionary];

nslog(@"%@", store);

}
```

this NSLog returns nothing and in the debugger all of stores class vars are empty showing nothing has been assigned. I am 100% positive the dictionary vars being used in the assignData method have the correct valueForKey values.

I think it has something to do with how I am using it here **[store assignData:someDictionary];** how do i catch the turned data so I can use it?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: okay I will try this now and let you know how I go.. but jsut to reiterate after I have initialized it I call it like **[store assignData:someDictionary]**  and then store will have the values avalible?

Comment: Yeah, I explained it a bit better in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `store` object is never initialized so it will be `nil` thats obvious isn't it. Initialize the store object first, then call its instance methods onto it. And by doing that, you'll have a storageclass object which is properly assigned with some dictionary already.

And if you want to have a storageclass object like your code shows, you should make your `(storageclass)assignData:(NSDictionary *)dictionary` method a class method instead of an instance method by putting a `+` sign

```
+(storageclass*)assignData:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
```

Then properly initialize it and assign the data (dictionary to variables) accordingly and return it to the caller. For example :-
in `.m` file

```
+(storageclass*)assignData:(NSDictionary *)dictionary{
        storageclass *test = [[storageclass alloc] init];
        if (test) {
           test.someDict = dictionary;
        }
    return test;
}
```

Then use this class method in your view controller as

```
- (void)getstoreready {
    store =  [storageClass assignData:someDictionary];
    nslog(@"%@", store);
}
```

**Also** Do follow the naming convention for classes and instances. A class's name must start with a capital letter only and the opposite for any class instances.

Comment: okay I have done the things you have outlined, however I am getting errors on the variables in my storageClass **Instance variable 'manu' accessed in class method**

Comment: @HurkNburkS What did you do in your class method declaration. I edited for the class method declaration.

Comment: I got rid of that instance var problem, I missed the point where you used **test.someDict** I was missing the classname **test** I have not got it looking exatly like you have above how ever I am getting an error **cannot init a class object** I would like to know where **store** came from in your method getstoreready..

Comment: store is the property you declared in your view controller file.

Comment: Ok i missed something, now check the class method definition.

Comment: whoops.. had a brain fade there :P:P So currently when I call  "store = [storageClass assignData:someDictionary];" the thread enters that then when it reaches the line with the init I get this error ** *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[storageclass<0xf902c> init]: cannot init a class object.'**

Comment: @HurkNburkS Its because the faulty class method definition. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

```
In User.h

    @interface User : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *name;

    - (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

    + (NSArray *)usersFromArray:(NSArray *)array;

    @end

In User.m
    - (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            if (dictionary)
            {
                self.name = dictionary[@"kUserName"];
            }
        }
            return self;
    }

    + (NSArray *)usersFromArray:(NSArray *)array
    {
        NSMutableArray *users = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
            User *user = [[User alloc]initWithDictionary:dict];
            [users addObject:user];
        }
        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                                                                     ascending:YES];
        return [users sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
    }

In ViewController.m
```

import "User.h"

```
    self.currentArray = [User usersFromArray:array];
```